# How can I improve the speed of this shortest path/shortcut(array graph DS) solution?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

Given a maze as an array of arrays where 1 is a wall and 0 is a passable area:

```
Must include start node in distance, if you BFS this it will give you 21.

[0][0] is the start point.

    |
[   V
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]<--   [-1][-1] is the end point.
]
```

We must find the shortest path possible, we can remove one '1' to help create a shortcut.

The shortcut that creates the shortest path is changing [1][0] to 0, opening a path that makes the distance 11.

```
[
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
-->[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
return 11
```

My original thought process was run through every element and check if it's == 1, then do a bfs compare the distance with the min.

But ofcourse that was too slow. So I thought running through every element and check if it's 1, then see if it has exactly two neighbors that are passable because that seems to the only possible case where a shortcut is meaningful.

Here is my code:

```
import copy
def bfs(maze):
    visited = set()
    queue = []
    mazeHeight = len(maze)
    mazeWidth = len(maze[0])
    queue.append(((0,0),1))

    while queue:
        yx,distance = queue.pop(0)
        y,x = yx
        visited.add(yx)
        if yx == (mazeHeight-1,mazeWidth-1):
            return distance

        if y+1 < mazeHeight:
            if not maze[y+1][x] and (y+1,x) not in visited:
                queue.append(((y+1,x),distance+1))

        if y-1 >= 0:
            if not maze[y-1][x] and (y-1,x) not in visited:
                queue.append(((y-1,x),distance+1))

        if x+1 < mazeWidth:
            if not maze[y][x+1] and (y,x+1) not in visited:
                queue.append(((y,x+1),distance+1))

        if x-1 >= 0:
            if not maze[y][x-1] and (y,x-1) not in visited:
                queue.append(((y,x-1),distance+1))

    return False

def answer(maze):
    min = bfs(maze)
    mazeHeight = len(maze)
    mazeWidth = len(maze[0])
    for y in range(mazeHeight):
        for x in range(mazeWidth):
            if maze[y][x]:
                oneNeighbors = 0
                if y+1 < mazeHeight:
                    if not maze[y+1][x]:
                        oneNeighbors += 1

                if y-1 >= 0:
                    if not maze[y-1][x]:
                        oneNeighbors += 1

                if x+1 < mazeWidth:
                    if not maze[y][x+1]:
                        oneNeighbors += 1

                if x-1 >= 0:
                    if not maze[y][x-1]:
                        oneNeighbors += 1
                if oneNeighbors == 2:
                    tmpMaze = copy.deepcopy(maze)
                    tmpMaze[y][x] = 0
                    tmpMin = bfs(tmpMaze)
                    if tmpMin < min:
                        min = tmpMin

    return min


print(answer([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]))
```

Any suggestions to improve the speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track. The following approach can be considered:

1. Form a graph of `n x m` nodes where `n` and `m` are the dimensions of the maze matrix.
2. There is an edge of cost **zero** between two nodes if they are adjacent `0`s. There is an edge of cost **one** between two nodes if they are both `0`s separated by a `1`.

(Note that there shall be two costs that you shall need to maintain for each path, one is the above `zero-one` cost and the other is the number of nodes in the path to keep track of the minimum).

3. Then perform BFS and consider only paths that have a `zero-one cost <= 1`.
4. This shall give you a linear time algorithm (linear in number of nodes).

Following code may contain bugs but it should get you started.

```
def bfs(maze):
    visited = set()
    queue = []
    mazeHeight = len(maze)
    mazeWidth = len(maze[0])
    queue.append(((0,0),1,0))    

    while queue:
        yx,distance, cost = queue.pop(0)
        y,x = yx
        visited.add(yx)
        if yx == (mazeHeight-1,mazeWidth-1):
            return distance

        if y+1 < mazeHeight:
            if not maze[y+1][x] and (y+1,x) not in visited:
                queue.append(((y+1,x),distance+1, cost))

        if y-1 >= 0:
            if not maze[y-1][x] and (y-1,x) not in visited:
                queue.append(((y-1,x),distance+1, cost))

        if x+1 < mazeWidth:
            if not maze[y][x+1] and (y,x+1) not in visited:
                queue.append(((y,x+1),distance+1, cost))

        if x-1 >= 0:
            if not maze[y][x-1] and (y,x-1) not in visited:
                queue.append(((y,x-1),distance+1, cost))

        if cost == 0:
            if y+2 < mazeHeight:
                if not maze[y+2][x] and (y+2,x) not in visited and maze[y+1][x] == 1:
                    queue.append(((y+2,x),distance+2, cost+1))

            if y-1 >= 0:
                if not maze[y-2][x] and (y-2,x) not in visited  and maze[y-1][x] == 1:
                    queue.append(((y-2,x),distance+2, cost+1))

            if x+1 < mazeWidth:
                if not maze[y][x+2] and (y,x+2) not in visited and maze[y][x+1] == 1:
                    queue.append(((y,x+2),distance+2, cost+1))

            if x-1 >= 0:
                if not maze[y][x-2] and (y,x-2) not in visited and maze[y][x-1] == 1:
                    queue.append(((y,x-2),distance+2, cost+1))

    return False
```

Comment: Any way you can you show the implementation in Python?

Comment: @JoelAntonioDelacruzParedes code added, may contain bugs but it should get you started.

Comment: Fixed the bugs and what your doing makes sense but it still isn't fast enough it seems; the 'time limit exceeded'. Is there anyway it can be improved further? The height and width can go up to 20 elems.

Comment: Should I just do it in Java?

Comment: It fails two test cases. Weird.

Comment: Any idea what would cause the failed 2 test cases?